# How do these pointers point to more than just a char or a byte?

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I'm a high school student, recently started my final exam project using Arduino, and I'm trying to understand this piece of code I found in an example sketch for a radio transmitter using VirtualWire.

```c
const char *msg = "hello";
vw_send((byte *)msg, strlen(msg));
```

I was never taught pointers or even C at all, so I'm having some issues understanding how this works.

`*msg` is a pointer to `char`, right ? At that point, it should be null, so why can you assign a value to it ?

Also, what the holy hell is `(byte *)msg` ? What do these parentheses mean ? Is it a `byte` equal to the value at pointer `msg` ? How does that work considering it's a `char`? And why is it necessary ?

Full code for context:

```
// transmitter.pde
//
// Simple example of how to use VirtualWire to transmit messages
// Implements a simplex (one-way) transmitter with an TX-C1 module
//
// See VirtualWire.h for detailed API docs
// Author: Mike McCauley (mikem@airspayce.com)
// Copyright (C) 2008 Mike McCauley
// $Id: transmitter.pde,v 1.3 2009/03/30 00:07:24 mikem Exp $

#include <VirtualWire.h>

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);   // Debugging only
    Serial.println("setup");

    // Initialise the IO and ISR
    vw_set_ptt_inverted(true); // Required for DR3100
    vw_setup(2000);  // Bits per sec
}

void loop()
{
    const char *msg = "hello";

    digitalWrite(13, true); // Flash a light to show transmitting
    vw_send((byte *)msg, strlen(msg));
    vw_wait_tx(); // Wait until the whole message is gone
    digitalWrite(13, false);
    delay(200);
}
```

Comment: What other coding languages are you aware of?

Comment: Nit: `msg` is a pointer to char.  `*msg` is a char.

Comment: The declaration `char *msg` means that `msg` is a pointer to char. `*msg` is a way to dereference the pointer, and the syntax is subtly different in use than in the declaration.

Comment: `At that point, it should be null, so why can you assign a value to it ?` . Consider the code `int x = 0; x = 5`, and apply your question. At this point, x is zero, so how can you assign the value 5 to it?

Comment: How are these questions C? Is `Serial.begin` a function pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At that point, it should be null, so why can you assign a value to it ?

No, it's not null.

Consider this:

```
int x = 42;
```

Would you expect `x` to have the value `0` or the value `42` ? I assume that you would answer `42`

So why assume that

```
const char *msg = "hello";
```

will cause `msg` to be NULL? It won't.

Instead it is initialized so that it points to the string `"hello"`. Or more precisely - it points to the char `h` in the string "hello".

Also notice that you can assign the pointer to point to some other char later on.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char* p = "hello";  // Now p points to the 'h' in "hello"
    printf("%s\n", p);
    p = "world";              // Now p points to the 'w' in "world"
    printf("%s\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello
world
```

In other words - you can give the pointer a new value as many times as you like.

Here is another example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char* p = "hello"; // Make p point to the first char in the string
    do
    {
        printf("%s\n", p);
        p = p + 1;         // Make p point to the next char in the string
    } while (*p);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello
ello
llo
lo
o
```

Comment: To be precise, it points at the first character of the string "hello".

Answer (score 1):

`const char *msg = "hello"` - creates a pointer to a `char` and points it at the first character of the string "hello". [In C, there are no string types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling). The convention is to use a pointer to the first `char` of the string, and use a null terminator to denote the end of the string.

`vw_send((byte *)msg, strlen(msg))` - let's break this down

- `vw_send()` - a function that expects a pointer to a `byte` (`byte *`), and an `int` number of bytes to read from that memory location
- `(byte *)msg` - casts a pointer to a `char` (`char *`) into a pointer to a `byte` (`byte *`)
- `strlen(msg)` - returns the length of the string pointed to by `msg`

`vw_send()` reads some number of `byte` from the memory location pointed to by it's first argument. The number of bytes to read is given by the second argument. Since the second argument is the length of the string pointed to by `msg`, and a `byte` is the same size as a `char`, the effect is that `vw_send()` will read and do whatever it does with the string pointed to by `msg`.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, what the holy hell is (byte *)msg ? What do these parentheses
>   mean ? Is it a byte equal to the value at pointer msg ? How does that
>   work considering it's a char? And why is it necessary ?

That is a *typecast*: its purpose is to inform the compiler  to take what follows "not as it is, but something different".

In this case, probably vw_send() expects, as first parameter, a pointer to byte instead of a pointer to char. You have instead a pointer to char, so you use a typecast to keep the compiler happy. Note that typecasting is not always so simple; in this case it is ok because  char and byte are anyway very similar (if not the same) on many platforms.

Answer (score 0):

> *msg is a pointer to char, right ?

EDIT: As datafiddler points out: It is a pointer only in the declaration, so some people like to write "char* msg" instead of "char *msg". It's the same code but looks different. Even "char * msg" whould be allowed and identical for the compiler.

But beside from the declaration, or on it's own, it's a "dereferenced pointer to a char" -> a char. The context is relevant here.

> At that point, it should be null, so why can you assign a value to it ?

it is initialized with the memory address of "hello" (or, as told, more precise the 'h' in hello)
C/C++ doesn't set the value of a local variable automatically (yet?!). (only globals)
So the programmer can/must set it explicitly to a desired value.

> Also, what the holy hell is (byte *)msg ? What do these parentheses mean ? Is it a byte equal to the value at pointer msg ? How does that work considering it's a char? And why is it necessary ?

This is a cast this tells the compiler to treat whatever "msg" is pointing to (it was 'h' of "hallo") as a pointer who is pointing to a "byte".

*To get low level:
In the memory the 'h' would look like 0x63 or 98 or 01100010 (search for ASCII table) computers know only bits and bytes, remember
you tell the code that this number should be used as a character which means 'b'.
The function vw_send dosn't care about characters it does care about "how many bits shall be sent in one chunk" so you can tell the function "please don't care that this is a pointer to char, take it as a pointer to some 8-bit values (called "byte") and send!"*

I suspect the type byte may be a typedef (kind of renaming of types) to  "unsigned char". This would be of the same size as char but the value may be interpreted different.
I suspect further this is to stop the compiler to complain about wrong types during the call of vw_send(byte *, int) or similar. You can do this if you know, that the called function can handle the data pointed to as another type. Kind of, casting is where the (black) magic happens...

Comment: Your first response word ("Yes") is wrong, sorry.  (cmp William Pursell's comments to the question itself)

Comment: In the Code of the question there is no place where  *msg occurs without being a pointer. It's only in the declaration. But without context your absolutely right.